# Excel - Find all values in range that differ from the previous row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table with setting-values for different parts. Every time a Setting is changed, I need the part number and the setting it was changed to in a output table.

I read through a few possible solutions and posts, but all either have trouble when a Setting reoccurs, or when the length of the list changes.

[image: Input_Output_Example2]

For compatability reasons I currently need to avoid VBA.

Thanks for any help and ideas!

EDIT:
I expanded the example file to show that I have multiple - in reality 12 - different settings per part.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Excel 2016, Office Home and Business 2016

Comment: Though I haven't looked into it, it should probably be possible using PowerQuery

Comment: @JvdV I assume this will be possible and I would like that, though my M-skills are nowhere close to finding a solution to this problem :x

Answer (score 1):

Make a helper column, and put there the following formula (in C5, for C4 you just put `=B4`):

```
IF(B4<>B5;B5;-1)
```

Obviously, you drag and drop this over the whole C column. You then set up an autofilter, so that only values, different than -1, are shown.

Comment: This works great for a single setting column. I edited the question to clearify that I have a total of 12 settings. A filter-based solution would require me to arrange them below one another making it painfull to read the data, especially since I add calculations to each output table.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after some more digging and tinkering I found a pretty good solution:
Based on this article from the awesome [Dave Bruns @Excelject](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match-with-index-match) I found this formula:

For the *Setting*-columns:
`{=IFERROR(INDEX(Input[Setting_1],SMALL(IF(Input[Setting_1]<>OFFSET(Input[Setting_1],-1,),ROW(Input[Setting_1])-ROW(INDEX(Input[Setting_1],1,1))+1),ROW()-4+1)),"")}`

For the *Part*-columns:
`{=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(Input[Setting_1]<>OFFSET(Input[Setting_1],-1,),ROW(Input[Setting_1])-ROW(INDEX(Input[Setting_1],1,1))+1),ROW()-4+1),"")}`

Note the `{}`-brackets, meaning it's and array-formula which needs Ctr+Shift+Enter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A little bit simpler option - for `Part` col:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$16,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$16)/($B$1:$B$16<>$B$2:$B$17),ROW(A1))),"")
```

with table references:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Input[[#All],[Part]],AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Input[Part])/(Input[[#All],[S1]]<>$B$2:$B$17),ROW(Input[@S1])-1)),"")
```

for `Settings` col:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$16,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$16)/($B$1:$B$16<>$B$2:$B$17),ROW(B1))),"")
```

with table references:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Input[[#All],[S1]],AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Input[Part])/(Input[[#All],[S1]]<>$B$2:$B$17),ROW(Input[@S1])-1)),"")
```

[image]